# mysql stange slower when like with and

Tags: mysql, performance, where-clause, sql-like

I have 3 tables and I run a query with join with three "like" one for each table
If I add the "and" in where condition the query become slower!

For example

```
 select * from A inner join B ON (...) inner join C ON (...)
 where (A.a LIKE '%...%' OR B.a LIKE '%...%' OR C.a LIKE '%...%')
```

results in 0.0021 sec

```
 select * from A inner join B ON (...) inner join C ON (...)
 where A.type=2 AND (A.a LIKE '%...%' OR B.a LIKE '%...%' OR C.a LIKE %...%')
```

results in 0.0048 sec

I expected that the "AND A.type=2" cuts the most records and then the LIKE (LIKE %...% is much more time consuming instead of A.type=2)
so with and in where condition the "LIKE" have much fewer work to do.

So I expected that the second one example should run much faster but in fact is slower

Why happened that?

Comment: How many rows in each table?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  The tables are so small that I would not be concerned -- 2ms vs 5ms is not a big deal.  If the tables will grow, you may find that the timings flip.

Comment: The database schema seems like tagging for posts
A ( A_id,title, content, type(integer)) 150000 rows
C (C_id,tag) 50000 rows
B (A_id,C_id) (relations) 80000 rows

Comment: select * from A inner join B ON (A.A_id=B.B_id) inner join C ON (C.C_id = B.C_id)
where (A.title LIKE '%...%' OR A.content LIKE '%...%' OR C.tag LIKE '%...%')

VS

select * from A inner join B ON (A.A_id=B.B_id) inner join C ON (C.C_id = B.C_id)
where A.type=2 AND (A.title LIKE '%...%' OR A.content LIKE '%...%' OR C.tag LIKE '%...%')

Comment: I Added index for type (integer column) with little improvement but not enough.